# How to make custom Keras layer expect more than 1 inputs?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I've created a custom Keras layer (`MaskedBatchNormalization`), which should take two inputs (a tensor with values, and a mask). I've implemented the call function as follows:

```py
class MaskedBatchNormalization(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization):
   def __init__(self, **kwargs):
      super().__init__(fused=False,**kwargs)

   def build(self, input_shapes):
      super().build(input_shapes[0])
   
   #Overriding this method is the whole point of this class
   def _calculate_mean_and_var(self, inputs, reduction_axes, keep_dims):
      return tf.nn.weighted_moments(inputs,reduction_axes,self.mask, keepdims=keep_dims)

   def call(self, inputs, training=None):
      input, mask = inputs
      self.mask = mask
      # do something with input
      output = input*2
      return tf.where(mask, output, 0)
```

When I run this using

```py
x = MaskedBatchNormalization()((x, mask))
```

It works fine. I implemented the layer in a model:

```py
def create_embedding(x:tf.Tensor, edge_mask:tf.Tensor, params:dict,name:str="Embedding") -> tf.Tensor:
    with tf.name_scope(name):
        x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(params["dim"],name=name)(x) #(N,P,P,dim)
        if(params["batchnorm"]):
            x = MaskedBatchNormalization(name=f"{name:s}/MaskedBatchNorm")((x, edge_mask)) #(N,P,P,dim)
        return x
inputs = tf.keras.Inputs(name='inputs', shape=(30,30,4))
mask = tf.keras.Inputs(name='mask', shape=(30,30,1))
x = create_embedding(inputs,mask, {"dim": 30, "batchnorm":True})
# do some more stuff with x, ending in a softmax layer
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[inputs,mask],output=x,name="MyModel")
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy')
#fine up until here
model.fit(training_data_generator, validation_data=validation_data_generator,epochs=30) #Crash
```

However, even though the model compiles just fine, when I run the `model.fit` function, Keras throws an error: `Layer "MyLayer" expects 1 input(s), but it received 2 input tensors. Inputs received: [<tf.Tensor 'truediv:0' shape=(None, 30, 30, 20) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'NotEqual:0' shape=(None, 30, 30, 1) dtype=bool>]`

This feels like a bug to me, since the call to the layer (`MaskedBatchNormalization()((x,mask))`) is the same in both cases. How can I make the layer 'expect' 2 inputs? Or is there any workaround for this?

I have verified that the layer does get called with two tensors in the `inputs` argument when the model is being compiled.

Comment: Please include a complete example, the problem is somewhere else in your implementation.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy I've added the basic structure of my code. I know that it works perfectly fine (it has for the past few months) when I use tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(x) instead of my own MaskedBatchNorm.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're encountering is due to the fact that Keras does not automatically infer multiple input tensors for custom layers. In your custom layer, you need to override the build method to properly handle multiple input tensors.

Here's how you can modify your custom MaskedBatchNormalization layer to handle multiple inputs:

```
import tensorflow as tf

class MaskedBatchNormalization(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MaskedBatchNormalization, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.bn = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization().   

    def build(self, input_shape):
        # Since you have two inputs, input_shape will be a list containing shapes of both inputs
        super(MaskedBatchNormalization, self).build(input_shape[0])

    def call(self, inputs, training=None):
        input, mask = inputs
        output = self.bn(input, training=training)
        return tf.where(mask, output, 0)

    def get_config(self):
        config = super(MaskedBatchNormalization, self).get_config()
        return config
```

Then, you need to change your model definition to properly use multiple input tensors:

```
 inputs = tf.keras.Input(name='inputs', shape=(30, 30, 4))
 mask = tf.keras.Input(name='mask', shape=(30, 30, 1))
 x = create_embedding(inputs, mask, {"dim": 30, "batchnorm": True})
 # do some more stuff with x, ending in a softmax layer
 model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[inputs, mask], outputs=x, name="MyModel")
```

Make sure you pass the inputs and masks as a list in the inputs parameter of the Model definition.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have already implemented the `build` method exactly as you describe after I asked the question. It does indeed receive a list of two shapes (the correct ones), and I pass the first to `super().build`. However, the error remains just as before (after calling `model.fit()`). Also, the mask is indeed added to the inputs in the model defintion, that was a typo in the question. Sorry!

Comment: I managed to create a workaround by simply adding an extra optional parameter to the `call` method, like `def call(self, inputs, mask=None, **kwargs)`. This seems to work just fine, but feels like it is a bit of a hack.